# XML serialization of array of classes

Tags: c#, xml

**I have a class ClassSample, whose one among field member is memberList:**

```
memberInfo[] memberList
        {
            get   {     return this.A;      }
            set   {     this.A= value;      }
        }
Class memberInfo
{

        public short memberA; 
        {            
            get   {     return this.memberA; }
            set   {     this.memberA= value; }
        }
        public string memberB; 
        {            
            get   {     return this.memberB; }
            set   {     this.memberB= value; }
        }
}
```

**Now if I XML serialize the class ClassSample, I expect the ouput as:**

```
<classSample>
<memberList>
   <memberInfo>
        <memberA>0</memberA>
        <memberA>"str1"</memberA>
   </memberInfo>
   <memberInfo>
        <memberB>0</memberB>
        <memberB>"str2"</memberB>
   </memberInfo>
</memberList>
</ClassSample>
```

**but I get the output as:**

```
<classSample>
<memberList>
   <memberInfo>
        <memberA>0</memberA>
        <memberA>"str1"</memberA>
   </memberInfo>
</memberList>
<memberList>
   <memberInfo>
        <memberB>0</memberB>
        <memberB>"str2"</memberB>
   </memberInfo>
</memberList>
</ClassSample>
```

**What is the problem?**

Answer (score 0):

The output you are seeing is how the default XML serializer sees arrays. You are thinking in a more CLR object manner in which an array is an object which has children items, the XML serializer just sees it has a sequence of common objects.

You will see this same output if you convert a dataset into XML.

Instead of

```
< table >
   < record> 
      < column >
      < column >
    < /record >
    < record >
      < column >
      < column >
    < /record >
< /table >
```

it is just flattened records without being 'contained' by a table parent element.

```
< record >
   < column >
   < column >
< /record >
< record >
   < column >
   < column >
< /record >
```

With XML though this doesn't really matter because XML parsers know how to pluck IEnumerable results, for example:

```
XElement obj = XElement.Parse("ClassXmlString");
var theArrayYouWant = obj.Elements("MemberList")
```

The plurral Elements() will return an IEnumerable of XElements which then models the array you are expecting. To get the items in the array you then call Elements() on the array you plucked.

```
foreach (var item in theArrayYouWant.Elements())
    // enumerate items in array
```

Edit:
You may also want to try using the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) which tends to be more object-oriented than the regular XmlSerializer